# Returning only the most recent values of a query

Tags: php, sql, informix

I'm working on pulling agent states from a call center system and would like to know if there's a way, in Informix, to pull only the most recent entry of a value from a table.

The table I'm working on registers the changing state for agents, which I would like to present on a web page.  However, it registers every single change.  This is the query;

```
select a.eventdatetime
        ,b.resourcename
        ,b.extension
        ,a.eventtype 
    from agentstatedetail as a
        ,resource as b
        ,team as c 
where date(eventdatetime) = date(current) 
    and (a.agentid = b.resourceid) 
    and (b.assignedteamid = 10) 
    and (c.teamname like 'teamnamehere %') 
group by a.eventdatetime
    ,b.resourcename
    ,b.extension
    ,a.eventtype 
order by eventdatetime desc
```

The query works fine, but I am only interested in resourcename's most current entry, ignoring all the older ones.  Is this possible with Informix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You just need a sub-query to identify the most recent record for each agent. Something like (untested):

```
select a.eventdatetime
        ,b.resourcename
        ,b.extension
        ,a.eventtype 
    from agentstatedetail as a
        ,resource as b
        ,team as c
        ,(SELECT agentid, MAX(eventdatetime) AS lastevent
           FROM agentstatedetail 
           WHERE DATE(eventdatetime) = TODAY
           GROUP BY agentid) AS d 
where (a.agentid = b.resourceid) 
    and (b.assignedteamid = 10) 
    and (c.teamname like 'teamnamehere %') 
    and (d.agentid = a.agentid and a.eventdatetime = d.lastevent)
group by a.eventdatetime
    ,b.resourcename
    ,b.extension
    ,a.eventtype 
order by eventdatetime desc
```

You may need to look at indexing `agentstatedetail` to get maximum efficiency.

**EDIT**

Per your comment about avoiding the nested query and handling the skipping of agentid values already seen, that's a fairly trivial client-side solution. I don't know exactly how you're handling this on the PHP side, but you'd basically want to do something like this:

```
$data = $db->query("select a.eventdatetime, b.resourcename, b.extension, a.eventtype
                    from agentstatedetail as a, resource as b, team as c 
                    where date(eventdatetime) = date(current)
                    and (a.agentid = b.resourceid) and (b.assignedteamid = 10)
                    and (c.teamname like 'ITS Help Desk %')
                    group by a.eventdatetime, b.resourcename,
                             b.extension, a.eventtype
                    order by eventdatetime desc");

$agent = Array();

foreach($data as $row){
    if(!$agent[$row['RESOURCENAME']]++) {
        echo
        "<TR bgcolor='#D0D0D0'><TD class='body'>" . $row['RESOURCENAME'] . 
        "<TD class='body'>" . $row['EVENTTYPE'] . 
        "</TD>";
    }
}
```

The associative array `$agent` tracks how many records have been seen for a particular agent. When that's empty, it's the first occurrence. The exact non-zero number is not really useful, we just use a post-increment for efficiency, rather than setting `$agent[$row['RESOURCENAME']]` explicitly in the loop.

Comment: Hi Ret - this subquery definitely does the trick, but it doesn't directly solve my particular issue (although I will give you credit for it).  When I run your query, it takes 4 minutes to complete.  My query takes 15 seconds.  This has to do with the server that I am running the query against - the tables listed in these queries are not really supposed to be queried.  So, I am wondering if there's a way to run my 15 second query but use PHP to keep only the most recent entries?

Comment: As I suggested, you probably want to ensure you have an index on `agentid` and `eventdatetime` to avoid scanning what is presumably a fairly large table. If you want to simply skip over agent records you've seen before, that's an entirely other solution. See edited answer above.

Comment: @Kimomaru, I agree with RET an index there should help the performance  issue, but I suggest move to subquery the relationship with the other tables used to filter because this, depending of the volume of data you have at `agentstatedetail` (I suppose this is your biggest table) you will avoid scan unnecessary agent details records (not envolved at the filter) , then the main query will be used only to get the description of the data (not apply the filter into it, only the basic ID relationship with the subquery).

Comment: Having seen your other question with the PHP code in it, I've updated my pseudo-code

Comment: Hey guys - I have tried the code and it runs like a charm.  Over the last couple of days, as I thought about it, my thoughts were going toward this as well - create an array, add objects to it in each pass, then check to see if the object exist in a pass before echo'ing it.  I just want to make sure I understand this properly; the line !$agent[$row['RESOURCENAME']]++  it's doing two things?  It adds the object to the $agent array and also then checks to see if it's set before running the echo operation?

Comment: Also, one more thing, in case it matters - I can't make any changes to the Informix database itself as you have suggested (such as adding an index).  This is a locked down appliance and I'm really only supposed to be running queries off of two specific tables.  The query above pulls information that I really need, but it runs very slow, so I would need to settle for a 15 second query and post process it in PHP to get the output I need, unfortunately :(

Comment: In answer to your second last question, `!$agent[$row['RESOURCENAME']]++` does those two things, but critically importantly, *the other way around*. The negation at the beginning means "this returns true if the key does not exist in the array", and the post-increment at the end adds 1 to it, meaning it will exist on any subsequent pass.

Comment: Thank you, RET.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

If your query runs slowly then use [explain](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_624.htm) to see the reason and also analyse the index usage. it might be the:

> date(eventdatetime) = date(current)

condition. if you have a nice index on eventdatetime (which is *datetime year to second*?) then perhaps use it this way:

> eventdatetime>='yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00' and eventdatetime<='yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59'

where yyyy-mm-dd = today